# Find lines and copy them into a new file in Java

Tags: java, file, rows, editing

I'm looking for a small code snippet that will find rows in a file and copy the rows who match with the search strings. However, I'm afraid I could not find such a snippet. For instance, if I have in a file following rows:

```
aaaa aaa xx 
bbbb bb 
cccc cx xx
bbbb ax aa
yyyy yd cd
```

Good would be to have a function like `public void copyFoundLines(String searchStrings)`. As an example, if I want to search for aa and xx, I get a new file like this:

```
aaaa aaa xx
cccc cx xx
bbbb ax aa
```

Comment: Probably your method will look like this `public void copyFoundLines(String [] searchStrings)`, right?

Comment: Des, you're right - my mistake. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear, however here is a way to do it:

```
public static void copyMatchingLines(final Path src, final Path dst,
    final String... searchStrings)
    throws IOException
{
    final Predicate<String> predicate
        = s -> Arrays.stream(searchStrings).anyMatch(s::contains);

    try (
        final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(src, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dst, StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
    ) {
        lines.filter(predicate).forEach(line -> {
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
        });
        writer.flush();
    }
}
```